# Speed up two for-loops?

Tags: python

The code below is slow. Any thoughts on speeding up?

```
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
list_needed  = []

for val in dict1.itervalues():
    for k,v in d1ct2.iteritems():
        if val == k:
            list_needed.append([val,v])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps,

```
for val in dict1.itervalues():
    if val in dict2:
       list_needed.append([val,dict2[val]])
```

This is similar to

```
list_needed = [[val,dict2[val]] for val in dict1.itervalues() if val in dict2]
```

My preference would be to make `[val,v]` a tuple - i.e `(val,v)` which is an immutable D.S and hence would be faster than a list. But it may not count for much.

Comment: like the list comprehension. But need dict2[val] for additional parse-ing

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of the intersection expected, it might be valuable to let someone else handle the loop & test:

```
vals = set(dict1.values())
d2keys = set(dict2.keys())
list_needed = [ [val, dict2[val]) for val in vals & d2keys ]
```

Or, is dict2 disposable? If so, you could do:

```
for k in set(dict2.keys() - set(dict1.values()):
    del dict2[k]
list_needed = dict2.items()
```

I just came up with those off the top of my head and have no idea how performant they really are.

Comment: list_needed = [ [val, dict2[val]) for val in vals & d2keys ] is much slower than 
list_needed = [[val,dict2[val]] for val in dict1.itervalues() if val in dict2]